# LLVM IR can't access global variable

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to compile a program with LLVM and I produce this code

```
@c = common global i32
@d = common global i32

declare i32 @writeln(i32)

define i32 @a() {
entry:
  store i32 2, i32* @c, align 4
  ret i32 2
}

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %calltmp = call i32 @a()
  ret i32 0
}
```

and i get this error when trying to compile it to object file

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_c", referenced from:
      _a in a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone knows what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Try adding an initializer. E.g. `@c = common global i32 0` <- Or any 32 bit integer

Comment: It did work. Can you explain why ?Also you can post it as actual answer and i will mark it as accepted, since it did work ;)

Comment: @FrankC. With LLVM 9 I get the error "''common' global must have a zero initializer!", so not really any integer value. If I remove the `common` keyword it works with other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from the LLVM-IR Language Reference:

> Global variable definitions must be initialized.

All global variable declarations define a pointer to a region of memory and all memory objects in LLVM are accessed through pointers.

This is relaxed if you are defining a pointer to an external value, for obvious reasons:

`@G = external global i32`